# Whats wrong with the given Java Code

Tags: java

Code is

```
public class ctorsandobjs {
    private int a;
    public int b;

    public ctorsandobjs(String arg)
    {
        System.out.println("I got " + arg);
    }

    public void add(int a,int b)
    {
        System.out.println("Addition is " + String.valueOf(a+b)); 
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ctorsandobjs c = new ctorsandobjs("You");
        c.a = 12;
        c.b = 15;
        add(c.a,c.b);                      //compiler shows error here
    }
}
```

I am using Eclipse Luna IDE and JDK 8 ...
can you tell me why compiler is showing error here.....
"Cannot make a static reference to a non static method add(int,int) from the type ctorsandobjs"

I am new to JAVA...

and if possible suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` is a `non-static` method and so you *have to invoke it from the object of a class*
You have to do:

```
c.add(c.a, c.b);
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance and thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference non-static members (private int a; public int b) from within a static function.

Answer (score 0):

The `add` method is not a static method, so you need to call it on an instance of the class `ctorsandobjs`, for example like this:

```
c.add(c.a,c.b);
```